# Run "ipconfig/release" in Windows to do DHCP

Tags: networking, wireshark, dhcp, netsh, ipconfig

I am having a problem with starting my assignment because of a requirement that I can't pass through.

We were instructed to perform `ipconfig/release` and `ipconfig/renew` in a Windows command line interface. I tried the first but it said that:

```
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection while it has its media disconnected.
```

Our home has a WiFi and my computer is connected via a Wireless Network Connection.

I found the tutorial "[*" IPCONFIG / release all " The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation.*](http://techmavin.blogspot.com/2010/10/ipconfig-release-all-operation-failed.html)". I tried all the steps (even restarting my machine as per instruction) but the LAN disconnected alert is still persistent. I tried multiple "`netsh`" instructions online but my problem is still not stopping.

I just want to do it in my WNC. Is it possible to do this with WAN?

I tried `ipconfig/release "Name of my WAN"`, `ipconfig/release "Wireless Network Connection"` and `ipconfig/release "Home network"` but all three said:

```
The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation.
```

---

This is a screenshot of the instruction that I have difficulty doing in a Windows + WiFi setup:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an older thread - but still relevant.

If you are having this issue with the error, `The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation`, you should try the following:

1. Try running the network troubleshooter - just right click on the Network icon in the Taskbar and select "Troubleshoot ..."
2. As said above, [check](https://superuser.com/questions/270528/how-can-i-tell-if-my-ip-is-static-or-assigned-by-dhcp-on-windows-7%20check) and make certain that your interface's IPv4 configuration is set to "Automatically" (DHCP) acquire a network address, and not set statically.
3. Open `cmd` as Administrator. The easiest way to do this is to hit the Start button, type `cmd` in to the search box, right click the `cmd` search result, and select "Run as Administrator"
4. Run `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset`.
5. If it says "Permission Denied" or "Access Denied" anywhere in the output of those commands, you should uninstall your Antivirus if you have one installed. Ignore if you are using Windows Defender.
6. Reboot after the above.

If anyone has other fixes, please contribute them in the comments and I will keep this comment updated.

Citations:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/the-operation-failed-as-no-adapter-is-in-the-state/39ab2c22-e64e-45eb-b8d8-0e40768ee0a9?page=2

Comment: Failed!  Reset required!

Answer (score 1):

you may have no administrator rights for the machine and thus you're not allowed to release your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Change adapter settings from Static to Dynamic.

Ipconfig/release means the Adapter gives up its ip.

Ipconfig/renew mean it requests for a new ip preferably from a DHCP
Server.

If the Adapter is configured in the Static state its IP
is fixed and it cannot get ip from a DHCP Server.